# I am having problem with Web3provider in ethers.providers

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js, decentralized-applications, web3modal

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')
    at connectingWihContract (apiFeature.js:41:43)
    at async fetchData (ChatAppContext.js:30:24)
```

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);

This Line giving me errors

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')
at connectingWihContract (apiFeature.js:41:43)
at async fetchData (ChatAppContext.js:30:24)

Comment: Hi there, please explain your issue in details , some source code samples to reproduce your issue would be also useful~